# Setup SSL with Vapor 3

Tags: ssl, vapor

I am developing server using Vapor 3. I want to support SSL. But I can't find any tutorial or documentation for this. Can Anyone offer some idea?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, at the time of this post, a [Vapor 3 docs 'site:docs.vapor.codes/3.0' search did not find any information on how to setup SSL (or TLS) with Vapor 3](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=ssl&as_sitesearch=docs.vapor.codes%2F3.0&safe=active).

Vapor [issue #359 "How to use certificate in vapor 3?"](https://github.com/vapor/documentation/issues/395) provides the guidance that:

> *Vapor 3 only supports plaintext HTTP.* You'll want to add something like NGINX in front for TLS. The docs from Vapor 2 should help: https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/deploy/nginx/
>
> FWIW, Vapor 4 will include TLS support.

For Vapor 3, SSL can be provided via a proxy such as NGINX:

1. Proxy Vapor behind NGINX. See [Vapor 2 docs "Deploying with NGINX"](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/deploy/nginx/) or [Vapor 4 docs "Deploying with NGINX"](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/deploy/nginx/). *The "Deploying with NGINX" pages are generally relevant to Vapor 3.*
2. Then, follow one of the more readily available tutorials about setting up Let’s Encrypt SSL/TLS Certificates with NGINX. For example:

   - [Certbot: "Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic)"](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx)
   - [NGINX.com: "Using Free Let’s Encrypt SSL/TLS Certificates with NGINX"](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/)
   - [Digital Ocean: How To Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Otherwise, the yet-to-be-released Vapor 4 (which will require Swift 5 and NIO 2.0) is expected to have support SSL/TLS without requiring an SSL/TLS enabled proxy.